# use session username as "WHERE" in mysqli query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I know I am doing something wrong but I really would like to know what it is. I can echo the 
username of the session loggedin user using `<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>`but I don't know why it doesn't work when I try to query database using the same technique. my codes below

I include this in the page

`<?php
session_start();
$username=$_SESSION['username'];
?>`

and here is the code that was suppose to display firstname and user_id of the sessions logged in user

```
    <?php
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'browser', 'test');

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  exit('Connect failed: '. mysqli_connect_error());
}

$username = '$username';

$sql = "SELECT `user_id`, `firstname` FROM `members` WHERE `username`='$username'"; 
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<br /> user_id: '. $row['user_id']. ' - firstname: '. $row['firstname'];
  }
}
else {
  echo '0 results';
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: `$username = '$username';` <--- what's this?

Comment: Why use sessions if you're not going to be using it in your second page? Use `session_start();` inside all pages using sessions or intending on, then pass that variable in the query page.

Comment: trying to show that `$username = $_SESSION['username'];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$username = '$username';
```

[PHP variables inside single-quotes are not expanded.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) So now your variable is the literal string `'$username'`, which undoubtedly won't match any user in your database.

You probably need to set `$username = $_SESSION['username'];` in your second PHP script.

Comment: are you suggesting `$username = "$username";` actully makes sense?

Comment: @Dagon, no, but it guarantees you won't match any username.

Comment: `$username = "$username";` causes only global warming.

Comment: unless a user is actully called **$username** (gives me an idea :-0 )

Comment: @Dagon, an idea for a tee shirt?

Comment: ...my old trade. ^^^

Comment: `$username = "$username";` worked for me and now echoes the userid and firstname of the user who's logged in. so I shall enjoy the global warming lol. @BillKarwin

Comment: No, you shall enjoy lack of logic.

Comment: +1 to zerk, [*and this is why*](https://i.chzbgr.com/maxW500/7461525248/hFA8479D2/). @Fred-ii- thoughts?

Comment: ok, whats the best way to work around it without making the world hot? @Darren

Comment: @user3487121: just remove that line. It does not produce any observable effects.

Comment: @Darren *Thoughts?* --- baffled. Keeping that image reference lol